# Cannot refer non-final intent when using with onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I was having some problem when trying to move to a new intent in `onActivityResult`. Here is the code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
            requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        barcode = scanningResult.getContents();
        new GetBookByBarcode(
                new GetBookByBarcode.OnRoutineFinished() {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        String bookID = GetBookByBarcode.bookID;
                        if (bookID.equals("")) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Book not found, please try another barcode.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(context, ReserveBook.class);
                            intent.putExtra("BookID", bookID);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            BarcodeScan.this.finish();

                        }
                    }
                }).execute();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```

Firstly, I will perform a barcode scan. When `onActivityResult`, I will execute the `AsyncTask` class. When the `AsyncTask` class `onFinish`, I then move to a new intent. However, I am getting error message:

```
Cannot refer to non-final variable intent inside inner class defined in different method.
```

at the `intent` inside the else statement. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try naming `intent` to `otherIntent`

Comment: @Marcus Sorry but what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a new `Intent` variable. You're creating a new `Intent` anyways, so there's no point trying to reference the non-final parameter from `onActivityResult`.

The reason you get this message from the compiler is because only `final` variables (and effectively final variables in Java 8) can be referenced inside an anonymous inner class like that.

Comment: When I did that, it just stays at the scan button that intent. It does not move to the new intent after scanned. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because the statement `if (bookID.equals(""))` was true. Did you see the `Toast` message? @Denise

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
intent = new Intent(context, ReserveBook.class);
intent.putExtra("BookID", bookID);
startActivity(intent);
BarcodeScan.this.finish();
```

Try doing

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, ReserveBook.class);
newIntent.putExtra("BookID", bookID);
startActivity(newIntent);
BarcodeScan.this.finish();
```

Because as of now, you are trying to access the parameter from `onActivityResult` which gives you the error.